# Add an additional cost to flat rate shipping each 3 items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I'm running a woocommerce shop and using a Flat Rate shipping `$15`. I have written a formula to add `$1.25` for each additional item.

> 13.50 + ( 1.25 * [qty])

Sipping "flat rate settings | `$1.25` for Additional Each Item:

[image: $1.25 for Additional Each Item]

But I want to add this cost `$1.25` for every 3 items. I mean 3, 6, 9, 12 and so on...

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you use floor()? 1.25 + floor(qty/3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** *(2021)*

The following code will add an additional cost to flat rate shipping method each 3 items *(3, 6, 9 …)*.

You will need to change your shipping cost **with a simple initial cost** instead of your formula.

> You may have to "Enable debug mode" in general shipping settings under "Shipping options" tab, to disable temporarily shipping caches.

The code *(where you will set your additional shipping cost)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_additional_cost_each_three_items', 10, 2);
function shipping_additional_cost_each_three_items( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // HERE set your additional shipping cost
    $additional_cost = 1.25;
    $items_count     = 0; // Initializing
    $each_items      = 3; // Number of items (for additional cost)

    // Loop through cart items for the current shipping package        
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        $items_count = += $cart_item['quantity']; // Count cart items for current shipping package
    }

    if ( $items_count >= $each_items ) {
        // Loop through the shipping taxes array
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            // Targetting "flat rate"
            if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ){
                $initial_cost = $new_cost = $rate->cost;
                $has_taxes    = false; // Initializing
                $taxes        = array(); // Initializing
                
                // Adding to cost the additional cost each 3 items (3, 6, 9 …)
                for($i = 0; $i <= $items_count; $i+ = $each_items){
                    $new_cost += $additional_cost;
                }
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost; // Set the new cost
    
                // Taxes rate cost (if any) - Loop through taxes array (as they can be many)
                foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $tax > 0 ){
                        // Get the initial tax cost
                        $initial_tax_cost = $new_tax_cost = $tax;
                        // Get the tax rate conversion
                        $tax_rate    = $initial_tax_cost / $initial_cost;
                        // Set the new tax cost
                        $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                        $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                    }
                }
                // set array of shipping tax cost
                if( $has_taxes ) {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Don't forget to disable "Enable debug mode" option in shipping settings.

---

**Answer based on your 2nd comment:**

you will replace this block:

```
// Adding to cost the additional cost each 3 items (3, 6, 9 …)
for($i = 0; $i <= $items_count; $i += $each_items){
    $new_cost += $additional_cost;
}
```

by the following:

```
// Adding to cost an additional fixed cost for the 2nd item
if($items_count >= 2){
    $new_cost += 6.21; 
}

// Adding to cost the additional cost each 3 items (3, 6, 9 …)
for($i = 0; $i <= $items_count; $i += $each_items){
    $new_cost += $additional_cost;
}
```

Comment: Loic, is this possible if a customer add to cart a single product and the shipping amount will be $9.99 but when he adds another item the shipping cost would be jumped to $16.20 and then shipping cost would be added each 3 items by $1.45 as currently doing this function:

I can handle the shipping cost by this part of your function:

// HERE set your additional shipping cost
    $additional_cost = 1.25;
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

Advanced Thanks!

Comment: All is working fine! The first item shipping is $9.99 and when I add Qty.2 The shipping price jummps to desired cost $16.20.

But When I add Qty. 3, it returns to the first state at $9.99 shipping cost and then works as previously working. 

I used your both condtions as instructed. 

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi, can we display $5 of handler fee below the shipping cost of $9.99, if the quantity of the item is [1] and this would be added into total? Thank you.

Comment: I have add updated the code at the end for your 2nd comment… For your last comment, It's not clear. You should please better ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$number = 13;
$all_number = 1;
for($i=1;$i<=13;$i++){
    if ($i % 3 == 0){
        $all_number = $all_number + 1;
    }
}
$price_new_data = $old_price*$all_number;
$price = 13.50+($price_new_data*$product_quenty);
?>
```

Comment: why don't you add some explanation to your answer it will be more helpful.

Comment: Maulik, thanks for your reply too but above function worked for me :)